# confusing trail

Tags: verbs

Which of the following construction is the proper or more conventional use of the verb form of the word "trail"?
Team A trails (following behind - in scores) team B.
Team B trailing (keeping behind - in scores) team A.

Comment: 'trailing' and 'trails' in this context do not have opposite meaning.  If B has more points than A, then A trails B and A is also trailing B.  When walking, trailing is a voluntary act and you can't make someone follow you down a narrow path.

Answer (score 1):

*Team A trails team B* would normally be followed by an amount, e.g. Team A trails team B by ten points. Your second example is not correct, or clear in what you want to say. You are using the present progressive (but incorrectly). *Team B is trailing team A* is correct and does not require qualifying. *Team B is trailing team A by ten points* would be correct, or Team A is now trailing team B. (both sentences mean that team B is behind in scores, but the second example suggests a change of position. Team A has been trailing team B the whole game. This example uses the present perfect to express a time duration. I would suggest that the use of the present progressive is better, unless you're a sports commentator and don't want to waste time saying longer sentences.

Comment: I understand the question to mean that Team B has (and always has) more points than Team A and @Vance is questioning if **Team B trailing Team A** describes that position (meaning having team A behind them) which I don't think it does.

Answer (score 0):

**Team A trails Team B** is good.

In the second one using **trail** to mean *keeping behind* doesn't seem right at all

**Team B leads Team A** would be better if you want to use them in that order.

I think I see where the confusion might come from.

It's normal to say *Jim trails a bag along* to mean *Jim is pulling a bag that is behind him* but that's a different definition of the verb trail. See [Oxford Dictionaries (verb defn. 1 & 4)](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/trail)